# VSTemplate create dynamic number of projects

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-templates

I am trying to create dynamic number of projects during Visual Studio Project template (vstemplate) runs:

```
<TemplateContent>
    <ProjectCollection>
      <SolutionFolder Name="Setup1">
        <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="Setup1">
          ProjectTemplates\Setup\Setup.vstemplate
        </ProjectTemplateLink>
      </SolutionFolder>
    </ProjectCollection>
   </TemplateContent>
```

Can I somehow introduce variable to create n number of projects to be created?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found is to use EnvDTE object to create projects from temlate using Solution.AddFromTemplate method.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is with a custom IWizard associated with your template, and use AddFromTemplate as Alex suggested. The trick is to call AddFromTemplate after the initial project is generated. I wrote and posted an example of this in [The VSX Template Wizard](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsx/archive/2015/04/11/the-vsx-template-wizard.aspx) blog entry. And the source is posted [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Custom-Templates-Wizard-to-8bd2366a/view/SourceCode#content).